# Store number into a variable with 2 dec precision C++

Tags: c++, string, matrix, precision

I'm trying to store a float number into a variable (really I want to store multiple float numbers into a matrix).

My case is a little bit special.
I have a string matrix (`vector< vector<string> >`), some elements are numbers (as string) and other elements are strings.
The real string elements are in the last column, so there isn't problems with that. The problem comes when I want to normalize my numeric values between 0 and 1.

For example.
My original matrix is:

```
0.7     14      0.13        24      M       
3       10      0.4         1       B       
0.5     0.7     -0.2        0.2     M       
5       7       0.2         2       M
```

So, the ranges by columns are

```
[0.5,5][0.7,14][-0.2,0.4][0.2,24]
```

When I want to normalize my matrix, this is the output:

```
0.040000000000000001        1                       0.55000000000000004     1                           M       
0.56000000000000005         0.69999999999999996     1                       0.029999999999999999        B       
0                           0                       0                       0                           M       
1                   0.46999999999999997             0.67000000000000004     0.080000000000000002        M
```

That I get with the line:

```
dataset[i][j]=boost::lexical_cast<string>(floor(((1/(max_values[j]-min_values[j]))*(atof(dataset[i][j].c_str())-min_values[j]))*100+0.5)/100);
```

The question is:

How can I get my matrix simply normalized as this?:

```
0.04    1    0.55    1    M     
0.56    0.7  1       0.03 B     
0       0    0       0    M     
1       0.47 0.67    0.08 M
```

It's supossed that we know how to convert a string to a float:(`atof(str.c_str())`)

Thanks all!

Comment: You are already there. There are some numbers in the decimal system, that have no exact representation in the binary system. So your numbers are correct.

Comment: What are the rows in the matrix? Maybe you should have a vector of structures instead? Then you could have a structure of four `double` members and then a `char` member. That would also solve your problem very easily since you could then set the precision when outputting the values and keep full precision when working on the values.

Comment: If you still want to go with a vector of vectors of strings, then check out [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) and the [`std::setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) manipulator.

Comment: Hello, Joachim, The rows are examples from a phenomenon. I need parse data to machine learning purposes. So, the number of features is variable, the real string part is the output of the objective function for this example.

Answer (score 0):

A floating point number is very unlikely to be accurate.

You need to set the precision of values when displaying.

This is a slightly modified example from [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
int main()
{
    const long double pi = std::acos(-1.L);
    std::cout << "default precision (6): " << pi << '\n'
              << "std::precision(2):     " << std::setprecision(2) << '\n'
              << "std::precision(10):    " << std::setprecision(10) << pi << '\n'
              << "max precision:         "
              << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10 + 1)
              << pi << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
default precision (6): 3.14159
std::precision(2):     3.14
std::precision(10):    3.141592654
max precision:         3.141592653589793239
```

Comment: Maybe it works, but with `setprecision` I only can `printf` or `cout` a value, not store it in any variable.

Comment: @Carlos `std::ostringstream os; os << std::setprecision(2) << 12.34567; std::string s = os.str();`